# Take Pictures via Voice Command on a oneplus 7

Tags: camera, voice-recognition, voice-command, google-voice-actions

I want to take photos automatically if I tell the phone "take picture" or something similar. Can this be done with Apps like Macrodroid or IfTTT?

Happy to hear your suggestions.

Comment: See if this can work for you: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autovoice // Tasker subreddit has some good folks who can tell you if this app can do the job you are after or not.

Answer (score 0):

Google assistant can pretty well do that.

Set up Okay Google and say "Okay Google, take a selfie" e.g

Comment: This works but it would be nice if it takes the photo immediately. Plus if I repeat the speech command it doesn't work while the camera is on.